# How to set relation name in insert()?

Tags: 8

I'm trying to do an insert query on a external PostgreSQL database with Drupal 8 :

```
$db->insert('site')
  ->fields([
    'civility' => 'mr',
    'firstname' => 'firstname',
    'lastname' => 'lastname',
  ])
  ->execute();
```

I got the error :

> SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: relation "public.site"

My site table is in schema "test" not in "public".

For example, if I'm doing a `select()` on the same table it's working.

How can I tell to `insert()` to look in "test" schema ?

Comment: you has table site in your database

Comment: Yes because the select() is working.

Comment: you check your connection, it not find the table 'site' in database 'public'

Comment: public is not a database, it's a schema. The database connection is working so I can get my site data. But for the insert it's doing it into the "public" instead of "test".

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/1060476, some things don't work when they are not in public. I also see some hardcoded "public" cases in the connection class. My guess is that you can't use insert() for this but need to build your query yourself

Comment: Hum ok i understand the issue now. I will check the patch.